# sqlalchemy foreign key with complex match logic.

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a database with sqlalchemy.

I have two tables : `flow` and `krbr`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
import sqlalchemy_utils
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.ip_address import IPAddressType


Base = declarative_base()

## Define the tables schema

class Flow(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'flow'

    Id  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    First = Column(Integer, index=True)
    Protocol  = Column(String(10))
    Src = Column(IPAddressType, index=True)
    SrcPort = Column(Integer)
    Dst = Column(IPAddressType, index=True)
    DstPort = Column(Integer)
    GroupId = Column(Integer)
    Port = Column(String(10))
    VPort = Column(Integer)
    IpTos = Column(String)
    VlanId = Column(String)
    VlanPri = Column(String)
    Application = Column(String(100))
    Packets = Column(Integer)
    Messages = Column(Integer)
    Bytes = Column(Integer)
    Last = Column(Integer)
    #LearnedIPs alertable 
    #LearnedIPs learned-ip
    #   u'LearnedIPs new-ips', u'LearnedIPs subnet-name',
    #   u'LearnedIPs timestamp-sec', u'LearnedIPs total-ips', u'SrcSubnet',
    #   u'DstSubnet'],
    # 'MPLS Exp'


class Krbr(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'krbr'
    Id  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Src = Column(IPAddressType, index=True)
    SrcPort = Column(Integer)
    Dst = Column(IPAddressType, index=True)
    DstPort = Column(Integer)
    TimeNs = Column(Integer)
```

To some of the rows in `flow` is associated one or more rows of `krbr`.

A row in `krbr` is associated with a row in `flow` if:

1) they have the same values of `Src, Dst, SrcPort, DstPort`

2) They are close in time. i.e. `np.abs(Flow.first - Krbr.TimeNs/1000000000)  < threshold`

I am wondering what is the right approach to create a link between the two tables. i.e. given a row of one table I want to be able to get the rows of the other table.

I do not know much of sqlalchemy. I guess that I should define a foreign key but I do not know how to enforce such a complex relationship.

Comment: I don't think fuzzy foreign key logic like you suggest in point 2 is possible - a foreign key needs to uniquely identify a row within another table

Comment: So the right way to do it is to create a new column in each table that is defined as `Src:SrcPort_Dst:DstPort_time_interval`   and then to use that column as foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of 'Handling Multiple Join Paths':

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    billing_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))
    shipping_address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"))

    billing_address = relationship("Address")
    shipping_address = relationship("Address")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    state = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)
```

More info about 'Handling Multiple Join Paths' in you can find at 
[SQLAlchemy 0.9 Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)

Comment: This will raise during mapper configuration time. There's nothing that'd tell SQLA which foreign key the relationships should use. You'll need to pass the `foreign_keys` argument to `relationship()`.